# ¿Cómo puedo validar máximos de rangos en entre dos input date?

Tags: php, bootstrap, formularios

Tengo el siguiente código.

```
<h6>Selecciona el rango de fechas y horarios:</h6><br>
            Dia Desde:
            <input type="date" name="from" value="<?php echo date("d-m-y"); ?>"><br><br>
            Dia Hasta:
            <input type="date" name="to" value="<?php echo date("d-m-y"); ?>"><br><br>

<input type='button' id='calcular' value='Generar gráfico' class="btn btn-primary mb-2" />
```

Lo que quiero es que al momento de hacer clic en el botón de 'Generar gráfico' valide que entre las dos fechas elegidas anteriormente no exista un rango mayor a 90 días de diferencia.

¿Se puede hacer?, ¿Qué se les ocurre?.

Answer (score 2):

Intenta hacer lo siguiente:

```
$fechaInicial = $_POST['from'];
$fechaFinal = $_POST['to'];

$fechaI = new DateTime($fechaInicial);
$fechaF = new DateTime($fechaFinal);
$diferencia = $fechaI->diff($fechaF);

if($diferencia->days > 90){
    echo "El rango de dias entre fechas es mayor a 90 dias";
}else{
    echo "El rango esta entre los 90 dias";
}
```

Ya de esta manera podrias aplicarlo a tu necesidad.